# Python 2.7.10 Checking if an input is an integer using int()

Tags: python

i am new to python and am currently trying to write a piece of code for a maths quiz to ensure the user inputs an integer for the answer without the program crashing . i have tried to do this

```
    user_answer=raw_input("enter your answer:")
    while user_answer!=int(user_answer):
      user_answer=raw_input("please enter an integer")
```

but it always crashes when I run it and says

```
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

Is there a way to use `user_answer!=int(user_answer)` to check if my string is an integer?Thanks

Comment: Post all code as text. Never link to images of code.

Comment: `int` _attempts_ to convert a string to an integer, but it may not succeed. This is key.

Comment: You probably are looking for [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](//stackoverflow.com/q/23294658)

Comment: @ForceBru also key is the fact its *convert to integer* not *check if integer* as I've seen people think that it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your raw input is a `str`. `str` will never equal an `int`. Do your validation in a `try...except`

```
try:
    user_answer = int(user_answer)
except:
    pass
```

For reuse purposes you can wrap that chunk in its own method:

```
def clean_user_answer(user_answer):
    try:
        return int(user_answer)
    except:
        return None
```

Use it in a validate method:

```
def user_answer_is_valid(user_answer):
    clean_answer = clean_user_answer(user_answer):
    return clean_answer is not None
```

Then implement it in your code:

```
user_answer=raw_input("enter your answer:")
while not user_answer_is_valid(user_answer):
  user_answer=raw_input("please enter an integer")
```

Comment: Thank you, this code worked worked well for me. But can i ask how would i be able to repeat it using `while` so it would keep repeating this process if the input was still incorrect? Because you can't do `while user_answer!=int(user_answer):`